# AWS CIDR is not within the CIDR ranges of VPC

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-vpc, amazon-rds

Right now i have a public subnet : CIDR 10.0.0.0/24
I want to add a new subnet on my current vpc to be able to use RDS service.

When i try to add a new subnet with CIDR, i got this message :

```
10.0.1.0/24 CIDR is not within the CIDR ranges of VPC
```

My current VPC is 10.0.0.0/24

Any help ?

Comment: did you mean 'Right now i have a VPC"? Otherwise it makes not much sense

Answer (score 10, accepted):

AWS is correct.

10.0.0.0/24 is 10.0.0.0 to 10.0.0.255. You're trying to add something outside this range, 10.0.1.x

You probably meant to create your VPC as 10.0.0.0/16.

Answer (score 3):

VPC CIDR should be 10.0.0.0/16.
Public Subnet and private subnets CIDR should match with 2 bytes of VPC CIDR
i.e 10.0.6.0/24 ; 10.0.24.0/24

Answer (score 0):

The CIDR block that represents the range of IP addresses for the subnet; for example, 10.0.0.0/24. Block sizes must be between a /16 netmask and /28 netmask, and can be the same size or a subset of your VPC.

if you VPC CIDR is 10.0.0.24 for subnet also write same. This worked for me.