# "AWS CIDR is not within the CIDR ranges of VPC", but it is?

Tags: amazon-vpc, cidr

many [questions](https://serverfault.com/questions/843379/aws-cidr-is-not-within-the-cidr-ranges-of-vpc) on this, but this time doesn't seem as obvious as the others.

I'm trying to split a VPC in two subnets.

I start with VPC `10.0.0.0/24`, 254+1 IPs, from 10.0.0.1 to 10.0.0.255

I create the first subnet with `10.0.0.0/25`, which should reserve one `0` bit of the address. Gives me 126+1 IPs from 10.0.0.1 to 10.0.0.127. Works fine.

The next subnet i try `10.0.0.128/25`, which is the same as before but reserving the `1` bit instead. Should gives me IPs from 10.0.0.128 to 10.0.0.255. But fails with "not within the CIDR ranges of VPC"... But why isn't it?

```
vpc: .0 ----------------- .255
sn1: .0 --- .127
sn2:             .128 --- .255
```

Comment: Your subnetting is correct, if that helps.

Comment: Thank you. It does help. For now i'm working around this by wasting tons of addresses splitting a /16 into /24s.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I cannot reproduce your claim:

[image: vpc]

[image: subnets]

Comment: Thank you. Created a new VPC with same values and everything worked. Will just move things to the new one and write this one off as an AWS glitch.